# Changing the background color of the Georeferencer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, qgis-2.6

Is there a way to change the background color of the ***Georeferencer*** in QGIS? What I mean is, can I somewhere change the color that *does not belong* to the image that is about to be georeferenced?

Let’s say I have a world file or I know the coordinates of the corners of my image, then, in the following example, I would have a hard time placing the points exactly as I cannot clearly differentiate between my image and the white background of the Georeferencer:

[image: lower left corner]
*lower left corner*

[image: upper right corner]
*upper right corner*

I am open to any suggestions, including Python.

Comment: If a "quick-and-dirty" workaround is also of interest for you then you could just draw a polygon that has a slightly bigger extent as the raster image and use the clipper tool with this polygon as mask layer. you will end up with a black margin around your white image-background.